# mysql trigger - putting price against a number

Tags: mysql

I have a table named ‘Prices’ and a table named ‘Ranges_and_prices’. The ‘Ranges_and_prices’ table stores ranges with a price against them (i.e: 1-20, £10) When someone enters into prices, when they enter the total_quantity; it needs to find which range it sits within and then put a price next to it. E.g If someone entered in ‘Coffee, 3’ it would see the number three and set it a range of 1-20, and give it a price of £10.

```
CREATE TABLE `prices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `range` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `range_and_prices`
--

CREATE TABLE `range_and_prices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ranges` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prices` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `range_and_prices`
--

INSERT INTO `range_and_prices` (`id`, `ranges`, `prices`) VALUES
(1, '1-20', 10),
(2, '21-40', 20);
```

I’m still kind of new to this, and i am just trying to understand triggers better. I assumed this would be an after insert, but i dont then know where to go from there.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

As I see you haven't got your answer and I am about to do almost same type of calculation on my application I am building I gave it a go on your example.

First thing first: you can not lunch a trigger to do an action on same table where trigger was lunched from. Meaning: when you insert a new product you can not make a trigger to update that same product right away.

You have to re-arange your tables and I suggest adding a new one. In new one you will have a [FOREIGN KEY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) that will point out to your product id so you can later [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) those two tables and get a result. In here you will store your wanted range price + product id.

I also made few needed changes to your table, I'm not going to name them all nether I am going to explain everything that is happening in trigger, [as it was a bit confusing at the time even for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61068752/selecting-values-between-two-columns-in-multiple-rows/61069120#61069120). Feel free to study the code and ask question.

I made a working example for you, how I think it should be done and this is a result:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
**Query #1**

    SELECT * FROM `range_and_prices`;

| id  | ranges_from | ranges_to | prices |
| --- | ----------- | --------- | ------ |
| 1   | 1           | 20        | 10     |
| 2   | 21          | 40        | 20     |
| 3   | 41          | 60        | 40     |

---
**Query #2**

    SELECT * FROM `product`;

| product_id | product | total_quantity |
| ---------- | ------- | -------------- |
| 1          | Coffee  | 5              |
| 2          | sugar   | 25             |

---
**Query #3**

    SELECT * FROM `product` INNER JOIN `range` ON product.product_id=range.product_id;

| product_id | product | total_quantity | product_id | range_prices |
| ---------- | ------- | -------------- | ---------- | ------------ |
| 1          | Coffee  | 5              | 1          | 10           |
| 2          | sugar   | 25             | 2          | 20           |

---
```

You can view full working trigger code here and test it by changing the last insert line: [View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9WZffZJqAFYV8pPCvYGfSb/0)

Hope this will be some kind of starting help for you. Cheers.

Comment: Ah- Thank you so much for your help! That makes a lot of sense. I’ll give it a go :)